# PhantomJS - sending a POST from the cmd w/ Curl isn't working

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

I'm getting an error when I tried to post the sample codes found in your documentation http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside.

```
Here is the screencast when I tried to start PhantomJS through commandline.
http://www.screencast.com/t/rDcPYZOi1

Here is the error when I tried to post through commandline using curl.
http://www.screencast.com/t/GnYoMBsUqXfR

Here are the other details that might be probably helpful for investigating what is cause of the error.
Files that were all in one location.
http://www.screencast.com/t/VJ7aK6igSTha

I have also tried to run this code through commandline **"phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options.json -outfile chartTest.png -scale 2.5 -width 300 "** and it works and rendered a graph.
http://www.screencast.com/t/G3U2QatAjgU

Just let me know if you need any other details to solve the issue.
```

Comment: I guess it's something with windows parsing. Try to use simpler example: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":"{series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}"}' 127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: I've tried your suggested code and run through commandline and it returned the same error.
Failed rendering:
SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem is with extra spaces and using `'` in CLI.

Working JSON example for windows CURL:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"infile\":\"{series:[{data:[29.9,71.5,106.4]}]}\"}" 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: @Fus - The issue has been fixed. Solutions can be found in this thread http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/phantomjs-sending-a-post-from-the-cmd-w-curl-isn-t-working-t28808/#p101056.